# If $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x-y|^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 1$ then $f(x) = f(0)$.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Question: If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and for $\alpha > 1$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x-y|^{\alpha} , \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(x) \equiv f(0), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x-y|^{\alpha}$$
Let $y = 0$ and divide by $|x-y|$ simultaneously to obtain,
$$\dfrac{ |f(x) - f(0) | }{x - 0} \leq k|x-0|^{\alpha - 1}$$
So that by the Mean Value Theorem there exists $\xi \in [0,x]$ such that,
$$|f'(\xi)| \leq k|x|^{\alpha-1}$$
So as $x \to 0$ we have that,
$$|f'(\xi)| \leq 0$$
so that $f'(\xi) = 0$, which means $f$ is a constant function so that $f(x) = f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: It's all nonsense after the step "as $x\to 0$". What you should've got is $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: You're assuming that $f$ is differentiable also, is that a given assumption?

Comment: Ah, you're right. The problem doesn't include differentiability of $f$ as an assumption... :-/

Comment: Try going like this: Using the start of your proof, prove that $f$ is differentiable in your interval and calculate the differential. Deduce that what you have is a constant function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
x_j=a+j\frac{x-a}n\tag{1}
$$
Then because $|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|\le k\left(\frac{|x-a|}n\right)^\alpha$, we have by the Triangle Inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|
&\le\sum_{j=1}^n|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|\\
&\le k|x-a|^\alpha\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{n^\alpha}\\[5pt]
&=k|x-a|^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since $(2)$ is true for any $n$ and $\alpha\gt1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}k|x-a|^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome, I have no idea how you thought of that (but I follow the work), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By your work and since you take $y=0$ you proved that $f'(0)=0$ so you can't conclude that $f$ is constant. If you leave $y$ arbitrary and you apply the mean value theorem and you pass to the limit $x\to y$ you get $f'(y)=0$ for all $y$ so you get that $f$ is constant.

Comment: So by MVT for $\xi \in [x,y]$ we obtain $|f'(\xi)| \leq k|x-y|^{\alpha}$ we have that as $x \to y$ that $|f'(\xi)| \leq k(0)^{\alpha} = 0$ so that $|f'(\xi)| = 0$, and $f$ is constant?

Comment: Yes. In fact you can without MVT and just using the definition of the derivative of $f$ at $y$ get that $f'(y)=0$.

Comment: I realized I used differentiability when it wasn't an assumption to the problem... now, I'm even more loss than when I posted the problem. :-(

Comment: At least you're now aware of your mistake :-)